# Can't see appearance in desktop settings to hide mounted drives

Tags: gnome, 22.04

### What I have:

I am running Ubuntu server 22.04.4 LTS 64-bit on a Lenovo E30.

I have the gnome 42.9 version running.

When I login, I use the ubuntu option (selected toggling (F1)
Here is a list of the installed desktops:

```
ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  259 May  9  2022 gnome-classic.desktop

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  296 May  9  2022 gnome-classic-xorg.desktop

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  248 Apr  7  2022 gnome.desktop

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  256 Apr  7  2022 gnome-xorg.desktop

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  292 Apr  7  2022 ubuntu.desktop

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  300 Apr  7  2022 ubuntu-xorg.desktop

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6832 Feb 16  2021 xfce.desktop
```

### What is the problem:

I want to hide the mounted network drives off the desktop.
I cannot see the appearance setting in the Settings window to do this. Numerous sites have said this is where I need to hide them.

### What have I tried:

I have tried to login using the gnome option but get an *Xsession error: unsupported number of arguments (2); failing back to default* at which point I cannot select the ok button and I have to power off the system.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 22.04 uses `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng`. Let's change the preferences inside that:

1. Run `gnome-extensions prefs ding@rastersoft.com` in terminal

[image: ding preferences]

2. Disable "Show external drives in the desktop" and "Show network drives in the desktop"

[image: disabled showing drives]